# How to add suporte for android TV using react native EXPO in Google Play Store

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play, android-tv

I'm using Expo, so I can't / don't know how to change the settings on Android Manifest to make it compatible with Android TV. My app runs fine on Android TV emulator and on APK install in a real device. The problem is with Google Play Store it does not recognize it as compatible with android TV so I can download from the device store.

I tried adding this code to app.json inside "android" but it didn't change anything.

```
"intentFilters": [
    {
      "action": "MAIN",
      "category": ["LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"]
    }
  ]
```

You can see how it looks on google play store bellow. It is not in English, but the last column translation is State of segmentation: Not joined

[image]

Here on a print of the device page:

[image]

Comment: Bump. Managed to resolve this?